# KSOAP Adding attribute to the xml tag

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-webservice

How to add an attribute to the XML tag using Ksoap in android?
XML tag to be constructed are given below

```
 <IndividualDetails>
 <GoodsTagMaterialQuantity unitCode="EA">20</GoodsTagMaterialQuantity>
</IndividualDetails>
```

find the android code given below using ksoap library

```
 // Individual Details
    SoapObject individualDetails = new SoapObject();
    individualDetails.addProperty("ExternalSerialID", "WAREHOUSE TASK " + taskId);
    individualDetails.addProperty("GoodsTagMaterialQuantity", actualQuantity).addAttribute("unitCode","EA");
```

output:

```
<IndividualDetails unitCode="EA">
GoodsTagMaterialQuantity>20</GoodsTagMaterialQuantity>
</IndividualDetails>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example Code:

```
    SoapObject GoodsTagMaterialQuantity = new SoapObject();
    GoodsTagMaterialQuantity.addAttribute("unitCode","EA");
    GoodsTagMaterialQuantity.setInnerText(actualQuantity);
```

Example Output:

```
<GoodsTagMaterialQuantity unitCode="EA"><![CDATA[1]]></GoodsTagMaterialQuantity>
```